# How to get full path from a list of files?

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file looks like this:

```
foo.html,9,0
bar.html,0,3
otherfile.html,9,1
```

Every row in this csv file, contains a filename. I need to replace the filename with the fullpath of this filename.

for example, `foo.html` should be replace with `c:\somefolder\sub\sub\foo.html`.

- I know that all the files are somewhere inside `c:\somefolder`.

How to do that with `Powershell`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Get-Content "file.csv" | %{
  # here I can get the row, but how to find the full path? 
}

Comment: should I run search for every file I get? or run over the folder and get all the files then I match the files from my csv against files in folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your comment that you know how to get the names from the csv and know that the files are in the the folder `C:\somefolder` you can try to loop this:

```
$allItems = Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\somefolder
$fullname = @()

foreach ($item in $itemsFromCsv)
{
  $fullname += $a | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $file} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname
}
```

This searches you the Fullname (path + Name) and saves it in the array `$fullname`.
You can then add the array to your csv and export it.

Comment: As a note to this aproach, you could also use a -contains or -notcontains to avoid scanning in places you know it would not be.

If you know the file is not going to be in C:\Windows and C:\ProgramData you could create an array $Exclude= ("C:\Windows,C:\ProgramData). Then when you loop you can check that the path does not contain something from your exclude and thus avoid searching through a whole heap of items you know the file ain't going to be in.